# JavaScript - During recursion type of variable changes from object to number

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have a function that pushes the number "number" to "output" array with the given number of "times". For some reason, during recursive call of a function, the "output" array becomes a number, and hence, push method ceases to work. Could anybody explain to me why the type of "output" variable changes during recursion?

```
function replicate(times, number, output) {
  if (output == undefined) output = [];
  if (times < 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (times == 0) {
    return output;
  } else {
    console.log(output, typeof output);
    return replicate(times - 1, number, output.push(number));
  }
}

//logs
//[] 'object'
//1 'number'
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the return type of push method on array is its length! never ever do this! that should be like this:

```
function replicate(times, number, output) {
  if (output == undefined) output = [];
  if (times < 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (times == 0) {
    return output;
  } else {
    console.log(output, typeof output);
    output.push(number);
    return replicate(times - 1, number, output);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the array's new length, not the array. So you are passing a number as `output` to your function, which is what gets logged then.

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

You could use `concat()`

```
return replicate(times - 1, number, output.concat(number));
```

instead, or push to the array first

```
else {
    output.push(number);
    return replicate(times - 1, number, output);
}
```